# DecodeError: Error parsing message for .binaryproto conversion to array

Tags: python, numpy, protocol-buffers, caffe, pycaffe

I'm currently trying to convert the .binaryproto file [here](https://github.com/chuckcho/video-caffe/blob/master/examples/c3d_ucf101/ucf101_train_mean.binaryproto) to a usable numpy array. I'm running everything in my python terminal and following some of the guides as given [here](https://sites.duke.edu/rachelmemo/2015/04/30/convert-binaryproto-to-npy/).

I can make it as far as seen below:

```
import caffe
blob = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.BlobProto()
data = open('ucf101_train_mean.binaryproto','rb').read()
blob.ParseFromString(data)
```

At which point I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)L
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

I've cleared and reinstalled caffe thinking it was an installation problem and it hasn't helped. I printed the data string and checked the length and both seem appropriate.

Or, as an alternative solution - is there another way I could potentially load the values of the .binaryproto file to get a usable mean? Thank you!